# Properties relating functions and graphs

Tags: integration

By considering the area of the region enclosed by x-axis, the y-axis and the curve $\ y=(1-x)^4e^x $ in the interval $\ 0\le x\le 1 $, show that $$\ \frac{65}{24} \le e \le \frac{11}{4} $$

I have managed to find the area which is $\ 6e-25 $. After that, the examiner made a statement that $\ 0<Area~ under ~Graph<1$. What is the justification behind this statement?

Comment: Justification is $\int f$ is area under graph.  Area is between length time min height and length times max height.  Length is 1.  Min height is $(1-1)^4e^1 = 0$.  Max height is $(1 - 0)^4e^0 = 1$.  So area is between 1*0 and 1*1.

Comment: $dy/dx = 4(1-x)^3e^x + (1-x)^4 e^x$.  the function is continuous.  $dy/dx = 0$ only if $x = 1$ at which point $y$ is a maximum.  So $y \le (1-0)^4e^0 = 1$.  So max(y) = 1.  So area < 1*1 = 1.  $y$ is always positive.  So min(y) = 0.  So area > 0*1 = 0.

Comment: @Faiq Raees Is the situation clear now? Any more doubts?

Answer (score 1):

We have that
$$\int_0^1 (1-x)^4e^x\ dx=e\int_0^1 t^4e^{-t}\ dt=e\left[-(24+24t+12t^2+4t^3+t^4)e^{-t}\right]_0^1=24 e-65.$$
Moreover $0<(1-x)^4e^x<1$ in $(0,1)$ (because $0<(1-x)^4<1$ and $0<e^x<1$), which implies that
$$0<\int_0^1 (1-x)^4e^x dx<\int_0^1 1\ dx=1.$$ 
Hence $0<24 e-65<1$ and
$$ \frac{65}{24} < e < \frac{65+1}{24}=\frac{11}{4}.$$

P.S. In general if  $m<f(x)<M$ for $x\in (a,b)$ then 
$$m(b−a)<\int_a^b f(x)dx<M(b−a).$$
This property follows from the fact that the integral of positive functions is positive. Let $g(x)=M−f(x)>0$, then $\int_a^b (M−f(x))dx>0$ which means that $(b−a)M=\int_a^b M dx>\int_a^b f(x) dx$. The proof of other inequality is similar.

Comment: If a function is such that $\ a<f(x)<b $, does that imply that $\ a<\int f(x)<b$? If yes, Can you provide a proof for that?

Comment: No.  It implies $a(b-a) < \int f(x) < (b-a)b$ and the reason should be obvious.

Comment: $\int f$ is area under graph.  The area is (b-a) units long, at least a units high, at most b units high so at least a(b-a) and at most b(b-a).

Comment: What I don't see  is why we can assume $(1 - x)^4 e^x < 1$ for $0 \le x \le 1$.  It's certainly plausible but I don't see it should be *assumed*.

Comment: @fleablood If $0<a<1$ and $0<b<1$ then $0<a\cdot b<1$.

Comment: Area of a rectangle is length x height.  The recatangle length x min(f(x)) must be smaller than the area under the curve because the the curve is equally long but always higher.  The rectangle length x max(f(x)) must be larger than the area under the curve for the exact same reasons.